# matlab integral error: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array

Tags: matlab, integral

```
syms h g t
gamma_d = @(h,g) 500*h*g;
C_gamma_d = @(h,g) log2(1+gamma_d(h,g));                   
V_gamma_d = @(h,g) (1-1/(gamma_d(h,g)+1)^2)*(log2(exp(1)))^2;
z_gamma_d = @(h,g) (C_gamma_d(h,g) - 1.6)/sqrt(V_gamma_d(h,g)/100);
fun_E_eps_d = @(t,h,g) (h*g)^(2-1)*exp(-t^2/2-2*(h+g));
E_eps_d =  int(int(int(fun_E_eps_d(t,h,g), t,z_gamma_d(h,g),inf), h, 0, inf), g, 0, inf); 
ans = double(E_eps_d);
```

Im trying to do a triple integration with syms. But when i convert the ans to double, it shows error:

```
Error using symengine
DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.

Error in sym/double (line 616)
    Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);
```

It works fine if I just do double integration, which is:

```
syms h g t
gamma_d = @(h,g) 500*h*g;
C_gamma_d = @(h,g) log2(1+gamma_d(h,g));                   
V_gamma_d = @(h,g) (1-1/(gamma_d(h,g)+1)^2)*(log2(exp(1)))^2;
z_gamma_d = @(h,g) (C_gamma_d(h,g) - 1.6)/sqrt(V_gamma_d(h,g)/100);
fun_E_eps_d = @(t,h,g) (h*g)^(2-1)*exp(-t^2/2-2*(h+g));
E_eps_d = int(int(fun_E_eps_d(t,h,1), t,z_gamma_d(h,1),inf), h, 0, inf);
ans = double(E_eps_d);  

ans =

   2.8865e-06
```

tried using `vpa`, it shows something:

```
 numeric::int((5734161139222659*numeric::int(-(2^(1/2)*g*h*pi^(1/2)*exp(- 2*g - 2*h)*(erf((2^(1/2)*(log(500*g*h + 1)/log(2) - 8/5))/(2*(2343413141819341/112589990684262400 - 2343413141819341/(112589990684262400*(500*g*h + 1)^2))^(1/2))) - 1))/2, g == 0..Inf))/4503599627370496, h == 0..Inf)
```

searched a while, most of people have same problem with me is because it contains symbol in the result. But `g` and `h` should be gone in my case.

Comment: `Undefined function 'r_1' for input arguments of type 'double'.`. Please add a [mcve]

Comment: sry, I forgot to ' clear all' before rewrote the example.  alrdy edited it, now it should reproduce the problem. @AnderBiguri

Comment: it doesnt seem that the second integral is solved.

Comment: I had the same thought, but if we get rid of the 3rd integral,which is `E_eps_d =  int(int(fun_E_eps_d(t,h,1), t,z_gamma_d(h,1),inf), h, 0, inf);` at 7th line. It works fine

Comment: No, I get the error with that one also.

Comment: I updated it at the top. I tried it again, with 2 integration it works. `ans =

   2.8865e-06`

Comment: Interesting. If I do it in 2 steps, then it does not work